# При нажатии на submit ничего не происходит

Tags: php, формы

Для разных типов пользователя и разных статусов задачи отображается разные кнопки редактирования, с этим проблем нет, но ни одна из кнопок не реагирует на нажатие.

Не могу понять, в чем проблема, консоль показывает, что запрос уходит, ошибок нет.

Сайт в действии: http://tanias08.zz.mu/all-tasks.php?id=1

Логин/пароль для типа пользователя "менеджер": manager1/123456
Логин/пароль для типа пользователя "специалист": programer1/123456

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку!

Код:

```
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
  {
    $id = ($_GET['id']);
    echo "<hr><h1>Задача №$id</h1><hr><br>";
    showTask($id);

    $result = queryMySQL("SELECT status FROM tasks WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $status =  $row["status"];

    if ($status == 'new'){
        if ($specialization == 'manager'){  
            if (isset ($_POST['edit'])){
                $error = $title = $description = $deadline = $category = $specialist = "";
                if (isset($_POST['title'])){
                    $title = ($_POST['title']);
                    $description = ($_POST['description']);
                    $deadline = ($_POST['deadline']);
                    $category = ($_POST['category']);
                    $specialist = ($_POST['specialist']);

                    if ($title == "" || $description == "" || $deadline == "" || $category == "" || $specialist = ""){
                        $error = "Заполните все поля<br><br>";
                    }
                    else{
                        queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET title = '$title', description = '$description', deadline = '$deadline', category = '$category', specialist = '$specialist' WHERE id = '$id'");
                        die("Задача отредактирована. <a href='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>Назад</a> <br><br>");
                    }
                }
                $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id='$taskID'");
                if ($result->num_rows){
                    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    echo "<form method='post' action='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>$error
                    <span>Название</span>
                    <input type='text' maxlength='128' name='title' value='{$row['title']}'><br>
                    <span>Описание</span>
                    <textarea name='description'>'{$row['description']}'</textarea><br>
                    <span>Сроки</span>
                    <input type='date' name='deadline' value='{$row['deadline']}'><br>
                    <span>Категория</span>
                    <select name='category'>
                    <option value=''></option>
                    <option value='programmer'>Программирование</option>
                    <option value='content-manager'>Контент</option>
                    <option value='designer'>Дизайн</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id = 'select_specialist'></div>
                    <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Отредактировать'>
                    </form>";
                }
            }
            echo "<form method='post' action='all-tasks.php?id=$id'><input type='submit' class='submit' name='edit' value='Редактировать'></form><br>"; 
        }
        else {
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' name='setEffort' value='Оценить трудозатраты'><br>";
            if (isset ($_POST['setEffort'])){
                $error = $deadline = $effort = "";
                if (isset($_POST['effort'])){
                    $deadline = ($_POST['deadline']);
                    $effort = ($_POST['effort']);
                    if ($deadline == "" || $effort == ""){
                        $error = "Заполните все поля<br><br>";
                    }
                    else{
                        queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET deadline = '$deadline', effort = '$effort', status = 'measured' WHERE id = $id");
                        die("Задача оценена. <a href='all-tasks.php?id='$id''>Назад</a> <br><br>");
                    }
                }
                $result = queryMysql("SELECT deadline FROM tasks WHERE id='$taskID'");
                if ($result->num_rows){
                    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    echo "<form method='post' action='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>$error
                    <span>Трудозатраты</span>
                    <input type='text' maxlength='2' name='effort' value='$effort'><br>
                    <span>Сроки</span>
                    <input type='date' name='deadline' value='{$row['deadline']}'><br>
                    <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Отправить'>
                    </form>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($status == 'measured'){
        if ($specialization == 'manager'){
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' name='effortOK' value='Принять'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' name='effortNOK' value='Отправить на переоценку'>";
            if (isset ($_POST['effortOK'])){
            queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET status = 'inprocess' WHERE id = '$id'");
            die("Задача отправлена в обработку. <a href='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>Назад</a> <br><br>");
            }
            if (isset ($_POST['effortNOK'])){       
            queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET status = 'new' WHERE id = '$id'");
            die("Задача отправлена на переоценку. <a href='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>Назад</a> <br><br>");
            }
        }
    }

    if ($status == 'inprocess'){
        if (!($specialization == 'manager')){
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' name='done' value='Задача выполнена'>";
            if (isset ($_POST['done'])){
            queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET status = 'done' WHERE id = '$id'");
            die("Задача отправлена на проверку. <a href='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>Назад</a> <br><br>");
            }
        }
    }

    if ($status == 'done'){
        if ($specialization == 'manager'){
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' name='doneOK' value='Принять'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' name='doneNOK' value='Отправить в обработку'>";
            if (isset ($_POST['doneOK'])){
            queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET status = 'archived' WHERE id = '$id'");
            die("Задача отправлена в архив. <a href='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>Назад</a> <br><br>");
            }
            if (isset ($_POST['doneNOK'])){     
            queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET status = 'inprocess' WHERE id = '$id'");
            die("Задача отправлена в обработку. <a href='all-tasks.php?id=$id'>Назад</a> <br><br>");
            }
        }
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Кода много ) а смысла нету. И еще интересно как в `all-tasks.php` принимается форма )

Comment: Ну извините, как могу.

Как "как принимается"? Submit отправляет значение методом post, условие проверяет если оно в массиве и если есть редактирует данные в БД.

Comment: Ну код покажите как оно проверяет и изменяет )

Comment: эээ... код выше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Незнаю что там с формами на клиенте, но на сервере явно тоже не всё гладко:

`queryMysql("UDATE tasks SET status = 'archived' WHERE id = '$id'");`

сразу кинулась в глаза опечатка, исправьте пожалуйста на `UPDATE` и это во многих местах и ещё, что кинулось в глаза на "коленке" так сказать это несколько сабмитов у одной формы. У одной формы может быть только один `<input type="submit" />`

Comment: Не помогло с проблемой :( Но спасибо, исправила!

Answer (score 0):

all-tasks.php принимает форму методом GET, а не POST

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.